# g++ error: invalid use of the scope operator (::)

Tags: c++, class, templates, scope, stdvector

I'm trying to build a basic string class like the one defined in the STL, but with a method to handle **split operations**. Here is the code:

```
//The header file "splitstring.h" for the interface
class ISplittable
{
    public:
        virtual std::vector<std::string> &split(char delim, bool rep = false) = 0;
};

class SplitString : public std::string, public ISplittable
{
    public:
        SplitString() : std::string() {}
        SplitString(char *str) : std::string(str) {}
        std::vector<std::string> &split(char delim, bool rep = false);
    private:
        std::vector<std::string> fields;
};

//The CPP file that provides the implementantion
#include "splitstring.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> &SplitString::split(char delim, bool rep)
{
    if(!fields.empty()) fields.clear();    //clear the vector if it's needed.
    std::string work = this->data();       //save the original string in a temp variable.
    std::string buf = "";                  //buf serves as an accumulator to work with each token separately.
    int i = 0;
    
    while(i < work.length()) {             //split the original string into tokens and pushes them back in the vector.
        if(work[i] != delim)
            buf += work[i];
        else if(rep == 1) {
            fields.push_back(buf);
            buf = "";
        } else if(buf.length() > 0) {
            fields.push_back(buf);
            buf = "";
        }
        i++;
    }
    
    if(!buf.empty())
        fields.push_back(buf);
    return fields;
}
```

The *ISplittable* interface provides the *split* method, which takes a delimiter (the character where a string should be split) and a boolean parameter, which specifies if the split operation should be repeated more than one time; by default the *rep* argument is set to *false*.

The *SplitString* class inherits from the STL *string* class and the *ISplittable* interface. It implements the *split* method that has been defined in *ISplittable*. It also has a **field property** which is a **vector** of type *string*, and it's used to store each token that has been obtained after the split operation: a reference to this vector is then returned by the *split* method.

In the **main.cpp** file I simply try to create an instance of the *SplitString* class and call its *split* method:

```
//The main.cpp file
#include "splitstring.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SplitString str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
    cout << str << endl;
    
    vector<string> fld = str.split(' ');    //Splits the string at every space.
    for(int i = 0; i < fld.size(); i++)
        cout << fld[i] << endl;
    
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

However when I try to compile my code, g++ tells me:

> In file splitstring.h
>
> Invalid use of '::' *(line 4)*
> ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'vector' with no type *(line 4)*
> 'vector' declared as a 'virtual' field *(line 4)*
> expected ';' before '<' token *(line 4)*
> expected class-name before ',' token *(line 7)*
> using-declaration of for non-member at class scope *(line 13)*
>
> In constructor 'SplitString::SplitString()'
>
> expected class-name before '(' token *(line 10)*
>
> In constructor 'SplitString::SplitString(char *str)'
>
> expected class-name before '(' token *(line 11)*
>
> In 'main.cpp'
>
> class 'SplitString' has no member named 'split' *(line 11)*

I've searched in the site for similar questions, but haven't found anything that could satisfy my needs.
I really can't see where the problem is. From the error messages I guess there is some sort of **error** that has to do with the **scope**. Please, if any of you could show me what's wrong with this code and how to fix it, I will be grateful.

Comment: If that's your whole `stringsplit.h` (or is it `splitstring.h`, or `splistring.h`?), you are missing a bunch of includes and an include guard.

Comment: From the look of the error message, it seems that's the problem indeed...

Comment: You need to included vector and string in your header file.  How else is the compiler to know what those types are?

Comment: Please don't inherit from `std::string`.

Comment: A much better way to implement this would be a free `split()` function, not all this virtual function + multiple inheritance mess.

Comment: Yes, your right, a global function way better than a class... it was just an exercise with classes and STL templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving these lines from `splitstring.cpp` to `splitstring.h`:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

The reason for this compiler output:

```
Invalid use of '::' (line 4)
ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'vector' with no type (line 4)
```

Is that the compiler doesn't "see" the header files `string` and `vector` when it is parsing your header file. Therefore, it doesn't see the declarations of the `std` namespace and the classes `vector` and `string`.

Comment: iostream is not needed in the header file as it is provided.  You don't want to include things in headers if they are not needed.

Comment: True. I'll remove it. Copy paste is a dangerous tool.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include at least header `<vector>` in header file `"stringsplit.h"`. So the compiler issues errors because it dies not understand what is vector.

Take into account that string literals have types of constant arrays. So instead of constructor

```
SplitString(char *str) : std::string(str) {}
```

you shpuld declare

```
SplitString(const char *str) : std::string(str) {}
```

if you are going to use string literals.

Also there is no any sense to declare data member

```
std::vector<std::string> fields;
```

because it is used only like return object of function split and each time when the function is called it is erased.

It would be better if you simply define a non-class function that splits a string.

Comment: Yes, I should probably remove the field vector inside the class.